# Weekday Local Notification Not Firing

Tags: ios, ios8, nsdate, uilocalnotification, repeat

I'm building an application that allows the user to have a local notification to repeat every weekday, because apple doesn't have a repeat interval for WeekDays I needed to create a local notification for every week day. I made a for loop looping 5 times the number of days in a work week. However it doesn't seem to be firing. But when I got to delete the notifications I see all five, the just wont fire. This is what my code looks like.

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = _alarmTime;
localNotification.alertBody = @"Wake up or pay-up!";
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
localNotification.alertAction = @"Wake up or pay-up!";
localNotification.soundName = @"sound_ring.caf";

NSCalendar *gregCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComponent = [gregCalendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit  | NSWeekCalendarUnit fromDate:_alarmTime];

switch (_repeatInt) {
    case 1:
        localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
        _repeatString = @"Everyday";
        break;

    case 2:
        //Attempting to create 5 local notifications with different days but same time.
        for (int i = 2; i <= 6; i++){

            [dateComponent setWeekday:i]; // 2 = mon // 3= tues // 4 = wends // 5 = thurs // 6 = fri
            NSDate *fireDate = [gregCalendar dateFromComponents:dateComponent];

            UILocalNotification *localNotification2 = [localNotification copy];
            localNotification2.fireDate = fireDate;
            localNotification2.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification2];
            NSLog(@"%D",i);

        }
```

If anyone has any ideas please let me know! Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

```
NSDate *startDate = [gregCalendar dateFromComponents:dateComponent];
            [dateComponent setMonth:0];
            [dateComponent setDay:i]; // 2 = mon // 3= tues // 4 = wends // 5 = thurs // 6 = fri
            [dateComponent setYear:0];

            NSDate *fireDate = [gregCalendar dateByAddingComponents:dateComponent toDate:startDate options:0];

            UILocalNotification *localNotification2 = [localNotification copy];
            localNotification2.fireDate = fireDate;
            localNotification2.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear;
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification2];
            NSLog(@"%D",i);
```

Comment: but... do you have in AppDelegate ... the code to register for sending notifications?

Comment: @TonyMkenu Yes I have that already.

Comment: @jack Where is declared " _repeatInt" in your code. Please let me know it need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I was finaly able to get local notifications to repeat every weekday, I added `[setHour]` and `[setMinute]` as well as changed the int in the for loop to a NSUInteger. Here is my code below.

```
NSCalendar *gregCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComponent = [gregCalendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit  | NSWeekCalendarUnit fromDate:_alarmTime];

switch (_repeatInt) {
    case 1:
        localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
        _repeatString = @"Everyday";
        break;

    case 2:

        for (NSUInteger i = 2; i <= 6; i++) {

            NSDateComponents *components = [gregCalendar components:(NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute) fromDate:_alarmTime];
            NSInteger hour = [components hour];
            NSInteger minute = [components minute];

            [dateComponent setMinute:minute];
            [dateComponent setWeekday:i]; // 2 = mon // 3= tues // 4 = wends // 5 = thurs // 6 = fri
            [dateComponent setHour:hour];

            NSDate *fireDate = [gregCalendar dateFromComponents:dateComponent];

            UILocalNotification *localNotification2 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            localNotification2.fireDate = fireDate;
            localNotification2.alertBody = @"Wake up or pay-up!";
            localNotification2.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
            localNotification2.alertAction = @"Wake up or pay-up!";
            localNotification2.soundName = @"sound_ring.caf";
            localNotification2.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear;
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification2];
            NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)i);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

They don't fire because the date you give them is invalid.

Here's how I generated the date for X number of days in the future:

```
        NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
        NSDate *startDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
        [components setMonth:0];
        [components setDay:X];
        [components setYear:0];
        NSDate *endDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:startDate options:0];
```